# delimit filenames containing spaces in shell scrip to pass to other programs

Tags: bash, sh

I have a music folder and the files are named by song title.
I want to move songs of one artist to a folder named after said artist like so

```
Music
|Apache
| \Feeling Good.mp3
|
|Marian Hill
| \Down.mp3
|
\Kaito Shoma
  |GAZ.mp3
  \Scary Garry.mp3
```

as currently all the mp3s are in a single folder.
The problem is: the files don't have the artist in them so I've got a script that iterates over all of them and returns a list of all files made by the same artist

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in *.mp3; do
    artist=$(ffprobe -hide_banner -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 -show_entries format -i "$file" 2>&1 | grep TAG:artist | sed s/TAG:artist=/ /);
    if [ "$1" != '' ]; then
        test "$artist" = "$1" && list=$list' '$file
    else
        list=$list' '$file
    fi
done
echo $list
```

now if I run it with `mv $(script "artist") artist` any filenames containing spaces don't get processed right and I end up with multiple lines of 'no such file'
printf doesn't fare better or my name is just Chef BoyJuaredumb

I tried to replace `$list' '$file` with `$list' '\"$file\"` or `$list'\n\"$file\"` and some others to no avail
either I'd get one line of

```
no such file: "str ing"

no such file: str
no such file: ing
```

or worse; both

I'm currently reading posix regex specifications for *something* I can use.
I've got bash 5.1 and mksh 59.c-1 (acording to pacman)

I really don't want to use mv in the script partially because I'm not good at parsing parameters and want to use it to list the artists of all songs in directory (requires work) and partially because I don't know how to implement flags like -m/--move or -h/--help

Comment: This is why arrays were added to `bash`. There is no good solution in POSIX shell (`/bin/sh`).

Comment: are you doing anything with `$list` other than displaying it (via `echo`)? if not, instead of appending a file to `$list` why not perform the `mv` on the single file (eg, `mv "${file}" Music/"${artist}"`)?

Comment: an idea I had and would've implemented as that echo is just to output the filenames, again I don't know how to implement flags as I might want to uniq the artists and honestly a lot of other things too I'll check the arrays too

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with all the filenames in a single string, because quotes aren't processed when expanding a command substitution. Output the filenames on separate lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in *.mp3; do
    artist=$(ffprobe -hide_banner -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 -show_entries format -i "$file" 2>&1 | sed -n 's/TAG:artist=//p');
    if [ "$1" != '' ]; then
        test "$artist" = "$1" && echo "$file"
    else
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

Then you can loop over that with a `while read` loop.

```
script "artist" | while read -r filename; do
    mv "$filename" "artist"
done
```

Comment: ayy, works nice! that sed command complains about not being terminated though! removing that space betwix the last two slashes fixes it and replacing the second script's "artist" with "$1" is a good suggestion IMHO

Comment: I didn't even look at that part, since it wasn't what you were asking about. You need to quote the argument to `sed`.

Comment: You don't need both `grep` and `sed`. If you use `sed -n` it will only print the lines where it made a substitution, so that will only get the lines with `TAG:artist=` in them.